# MKAnnotation subclass issues

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, mapkit, mkannotation

I upgraded to Swift 1.2 last night, and I got a bug I really can't figure out. The below code worked fine in the previous version of Xcode and Swift.

```
//MARK: Annotation Object
class PointAnnotation : NSObject, MKAnnotation {
    var coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D
    var title: String
    var subtitle: String
    var point: Point
    var image: UIImage
    var md: String

    init(point: Point) {
        self.coordinate = point.coordinate
        self.title = point.title
        self.subtitle = point.teaser
        self.image = UIImage(named: "annotation.png")!
        self.point = point
        self.md = point.content
    }
}
```

On line 3, I get the somewhat hard to understand error 
`Objective-C method 'setCoordinate:' provided by the setter for 'coordinate' conflicts with the optional requirement method 'setCoordinate' in protocol 'MKAnnotation'` I tried changing variable names and such, but no help. Does anyone have any idea how to fix this?

The class is for annotations on my mapview.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you do not require to change coordinates after initialization then you can use it that way. It works for me with Swift 1.2:

```
class CustomAnnotation : NSObject, MKAnnotation {
    let coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D
    var title: String

    init(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D, title: String) {
        self.coordinate = coordinate
        self.title = title
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are overriding a readonly ivar in MKAnnotation with a readwrite.

`var coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D { get }`

Comment: Okay. How am I supposed to solve it? If i change the variable, it complains im not conforming to protocol.

Comment: How about defining coordinate as `var coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D { get }`. Sorry, I haven't upgraded myself yet.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue so I just did this:

```
private var _coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D
var coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D {
    return _coordinate
}

init(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D) {
    self._coordinate = coordinate
    super.init()
}

func setCoordinate(newCoordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D) {
    self._coordinate = newCoordinate
}
```

That way `coordinate` is still readonly and you can use the `setCoordinate` method.